# Google geocode address resolution

Tags: geocoding, google-places-api

Why is it that certain common addresses won't resolve using the API but they show up fine in google maps?

1400 Welton Street, Denver, CO

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=1400+Welton+Street, Denver,+CO

Google places doesn't find it either.  This is a common location seems strange..

Comment: That's interesting.  Seems like it doesn't like your street number: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=1401+Welton+Street,+Denver,+CO

Answer (score -1):

Seems like an error in Google's map data.  When you put in that address to Google maps it does zoom in to the general location, but you'll notice that it does not show an exact point on the map.  If you play with the street numbers it looks like other addresses around that - 1399 and 1401 for example - do in fact return relevant results with the API call, and show a dot in Google Maps.

Bing maps says there's a "Pi Kitchen and Bar" at this location, so I assume it's a real location and this is just wrong map data.

I suggest reporting it to Google so they can fix: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088